# Prove that p(n) is equal to the number of partitions of the integer 2n with no odd parts.

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: Prove that p(n) is equal to the number of partitions of the integer 2n with no odd parts.

I know you have to find a bijection but I do not know how to show it.

Please help!

Comment: Is a part an element of a partition?

Answer (score 1):

Map every part $x_i$ of $2 n$ to $x_i/2.$

Comment: @TheCount It does though, he is describing the bijection between the set of partitions of $2n$ with no odd parts to the set of partitions of $n$ with no restrictions.,  $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)\mapsto (x_1/2,x_2/2,\dots,x_k/2)$.  All that remains is filling in the rest of the details which should be left to the OP to do anyways, proving that the function alluded to truly is a bijection

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, you have been around longer than me, but it is my interpretation of site rules that answers should be complete, including all details. I suppose it is alright that we disagree.

Comment: @TheCount Most questions on MSE are homework (and this one certainly is). It is morally incorrect to do people's homework for them, but it is acceptable to point them in the right direction (ok, borderline acceptable).

Comment: @TheCount I point out that I have been around *even longer* than JMoravitz, so I do know a little about the rules.

Comment: @IgorRivin, I don't disagree. But I take the stance that whether or not the OP is being academically dishonest is their problem, not ours. Although, having reread the rules to be sure, it seems this is in fact a valid type of answer. I didn't mean to step on any toes, and thanks for helping me get used to 2k+ responsibilities. And I did click on your profile to see how long you've been around, although that is only tangentially relevant. A bit cheeky to bring up... ha.

Comment: @TheCount I was teasing you (but if length of being around is a criterion, then, well...) Otherwise, the question is: why are we here (not, not on Earth). Partly, it is for a bit of mental gymnastics, partly to help people who need it, and my view is that writing out full answers to easy questions is (a) not very gymnastically challenging, and (b) not very helpful. Writing out answers to very interesting questions is another matter, because the devil is  often in the details. Just one man's opinion, of course...

Comment: See, the internet needs a sarcasm font. I think the main issue in situations like this is that it is tough to define "easy" effectively. It is easy for me to prove that automorphisms of symmetric designs fix the same number of points and blocks, but that's a fundamental part of my thesis. That's hard for people getting used to those terms. Heck, it's hard for younger/newer students to even see that the size of the power set of a finite set of size $N$ is $2^N$. "Easy" is very relative, and I think this question provides a great example of the contextual distinction...

Comment: Maybe labelling it as a hint is advisable? I dunno, but I don't like calling it "easy"... I was once a very real mathematical idiot. Didn't realize I had any talent at it until after college, really. But I digress. I'm just very sympathetic to confused students, even when their questions might be "easy". Feel free to chat me up if you'd like, but I won't be offended if not.

Comment: @TheCount I actually have never used chat in all my years on the stack exchange network, and tend to talk in the comments, despite robotic finger-wagging. But as for "easy", I absolutely agree that it is relative, but people can't be carried over walls, otherwise they will never learn. A push is helpful. The correct form of a hint for the particular problem would be:
`Note that an even number can be written as x_i = 2 x_i^\prime.` It seems a little snarky, but is not meant to be.

Comment: I usually say: "Hint: $2$ is even" or something, but I do it in comments. I'll admit, too, that a weakness of mine as a teacher is to tend towards spoon-feeding. I try very hard not to. I'm getting better. In any case, your push is a good one, to be sure. But I wonder if in these situations the OP has gotten so frustrated by the time they are even willing to resort to math.SE that it wouldn't be helpful. But again, that's their problem, not ours. In any case, yes, I also hate chat, but I get scared by the robotic finger-wagging. I feel like a mod will come yell at me.

Comment: @IgorRivin Oh holy crap, I just realized you're faculty at Temple. Not kidding at all, I am very seriously considering applying for my doctorate there.

Comment: @TheCount Well, by all means do apply! Temple has a very strong department these days (though, granted, algebraic combinatorics is not particularly represented - representation theory is, though, and it is not unrelated, as you know).

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you, I likely will. I am not particular about the kind of combinatorics, necessarily. I just like to count things. :)

Comment: @TheCount Good. I am not a fan of specialists :)